# Call Javascript from a button click event function in Jupyter Lab or Jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In jupyter cell, I have the following code, and I can see the it works with "hello world!" printed out in Chrome console.

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
my_js = """
console.log('hello world!');
"""
Javascript(my_js)
```

Now, I create a button in jupyter and move that function to button click event. Now, when I click button, the event is executed, but the javascript doesn't work and no output in chrome console:

```
button = widgets.Button(
   description='Button',
   disabled=False,
   button_style='', 
   tooltip='Button',
   icon='check' 
)

def on_button_clicked(b):
   print("on_button_clicked called")
   my_js = """
   console.log('Hello world2!');
   """
   Javascript(my_js)
   print("on_button_clicked call ended")
   
button.on_click(on_button_clicked)

display(button)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNEzz.jpg)

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: For anyone googling this, for mor discussion see: https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/call-javascript-from-a-button-click-event/10675

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an object of `Javascript` class, but then discarding it (as you are not assigning it to any variable, nor displaying it). This works with your first use of `Javascript` because when the last result of an IPython cell is not assigned to a variable it will be automatically displayed; this also means that you can skip `display()` call when displaying a button (if it is the last line in the cell):

```py
button = widgets.Button(
    description='Button',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='',
    tooltip='Button',
    icon='check'
)
button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
# notice lack of `display()` call:
button
```

but it does not work if the object to be displayed is inside the function callback, because IPython does not know which expressions to display and which to ignore. `Javascript` objects need to be displayed in order for the JavaScript code to be executed by your browser. To make it work:

- use `display` explicitly on `Javascript` object, and
- define an output area in which the object should be displayed in

For example, cell 1:

```py
out = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})
out
```

And then:

```py
def on_button_clicked(b):
    my_js = """
    console.log('Hello world2!');
    """
    with out:
        display(Javascript(my_js))
        display(Markdown("on_button_clicked called"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used Krassowski's solution with small tuning in 2023. Run it in a cell. I need to use a display call for out and button. And don't forget to open your browser's console.

`

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import Javascript, Markdown

out = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})

def on_button_clicked(b):
    my_js = """
    console.log('Hello world2!');
    alert("hi");
    """
    with out:
        #print(my_js)
        display(Javascript(my_js))
        display(Markdown("on_button_clicked called"))
        print("on_button_clicked call ended")

button = widgets.Button(
    description='Button',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='',
    tooltip='Button',
    icon='check'
)

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
display(button, out)
```

`